# What library (if any) is Stack Overflow using to make their tutorial tips for Documentation?

Tags: discussion

As seen here with the blue dots and one of the tips active.

It's really neat (better than most others I've seen) and was wondering if it's a standard JavaScript plugin from somewhere or if it was custom made?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's custom.

Kurtis mocked it up, and I slapped it together with jQuery.  Nothing too complicated.

Comment: Dang. I was afraid of that. Thanks.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Kevin was a bit imprecise in his answer, he meant "you should drop that and use jQuery"